# How to install ConTeXt on CentOS 7?

Tags: context

I'm trying to install ConTeXt on CentOS 7.2. Can anyone give me any pointers?

1. On CentOS 6, I was able to `yum install texlive-context`, but that package has apparently removed.
2. I tried the [stand-alone version of ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Single_user_installation), but the minimals.contextgarden.net server that they list appears to be down.
3. I haven't yet tried installing [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) directly, as I was concerned that would conflict with the built-in packages.

Are there other options? Any of these known to work? I'd personally prefer the first option or the second.

Thanks for any pointers you have!

Comment: installing TeXLive directly does not interfere with the OS since it doesn't use packages in the OS sense. It also doesn't install itself in the PATH and rely on the admin to add it.

Comment: Thanks @HenriMenke! I was able to get things working with minimals.contextgarden.net, and that got me what I needed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ll just summarise my comments here as they apparently helped to solve the problem.

- To 1: Even if Cent OS 7 would ship ConTeXt with TeXlive you shouldn’t install that. The TeXlive they ship is from 2012 which is ancient even by LaTeX standards.
- To 2: There are detailed instructions [in the Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Single_user_installation).  They can be summarised as

  ```bash
  mkdir ~/context
  cd ~/context
  wget http://minimals.contextgarden.net/setup/first-setup.sh
  sh ./first-setup.sh --modules=all
  ```
- To 3: There is detailed guide on this site in the question [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092)